# Avoid UpsertAsync in CosmosDB - run update SQL command

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the structure below in a Cosmos collection (where this structure will not be changed)

```
{
    "attribute1": "",
    "attribute2": "",
    "attribute3": "11181",
    "attribute4": "Text value",
    "companies": [
        {
            "companyId": "Guid",
            "companyName": "Value"
        }
    ],
    "id": "ec4c18d9-178d-43d4-a2b0-093b160bfd06"
}
```

I have a process which modifies the company list

Is there any way of running a "UPDATE" statement in Cosmos to update the Companies list only?

The current implementation shown below takes 1 minute which is quite a lot longer than I would like

```cs
public void RandomizeCompanies()
{
  foreach (var item in _items)
  {
      //Clear companies list and add random elements to the list
  }
}

public async Task ChangeCompaniesAsync()
{
    await ConnectToDatabaseAsync();
    await GetItemsFromCosmosAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    RandomizeCompanies();

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting...");
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var tasks = new List<Task>(_items.Count);

        foreach (var item in _items)
        {
            tasks.Add(_cosmosConnection.Container.UpsertItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.Id)));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Finished writing {_items.Count} items in {stopwatch.Elapsed}.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up resources...");
    }
  }
}
```

Something like

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>(_items.Count);
foreach (var item in _items)
{
    tasks.Add( Run update statement that updates companies list to be items.Companies  );
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

The current implementation is not ideal because I am serializing all of the document even though only a small part is being changed.

Comment: Thats annoying!  Im assuming this logic is the fastest it can be ?

Comment: Regarding the one-minute timing: not sure how to connect that to update vs replace. How many documents are you attempting to update at once? How many RU did you configure your collection for? Are you being throttled at all as you attempt to perform all of your updates in parallel? (the .net SDK has default retry behavior, so you could, indeed, be getting throttled, which would explain some of the delay in updating). Have you tried increasing RU to see if this runs faster? Also: You can check to see what the overall RU cost of each 'replace' is costing (looking at return headers).

Comment: I don’t know how to look at the return for each? If I increase the ru I can’t reduce it?

Comment: You can look at the `x-ms-request-charge` return header value (and the Cosmos DB docs have examples in various language-specific SDKs, if you get stuck). I'm not sure about your 2nd question, but... yes you can reduce RU for a collection, although if you increase it to the point that the number of underlying physical partitions needs to grow, then you will find that your new "minimum" RU will increase. First step is to see if you're even being throttled.

Comment: Ok I meant I don’t know how to do that within the asynchronous task syntax

Comment: Like I said - there are examples for looking at that. And I'd treat that as a separate question if you get stuck: not really related to upsert vs replace, and not something easily answerable in comments.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in another answer, partial updates are not currently supported. However, even once supported it is quite possible this will not be as efficient as if you had designed your model to separate static from frequently changing data. This is especially true for large document sizes with deep nested structure. These modeling suggestions below include using a "type" property to distinguish the entity type and with a shared "partition key" and "id" so they can be queried together. There are two primary scenarios to consider.

Scenario 1 (static properties and properties with frequent updates): In this scenario you have a large set of static properties and a smaller number of frequently updated properties. In this scenario model the static properties as a single document and the frequently updated properties as a second (smaller) document with the same partition key and id. If it is not smaller, separate more frequently from less frequently updated properties.

Scenario 2 (static properties and properties in unbounded array): In this scenarios you have the same large set of static properties but an ever growing list of properties in an array. This doesn't have to be specifically unbounded but when you have an array that typically keeps grows it is more efficient to make each element in that array as it's own document with shared partition key and id, and simply insert into the container.

For more information on some of these concepts see, [Data modeling in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this I will need to potentially re think my design but it may bring complications in terms of me linking this with my azure index which is currently synced with cosmos

Answer (score 1):

@Paul
Partial document updates are not possible in Cosmos SQL API. This is a feature request on user voice.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document